# Is a buffered reader br.readLine() 1 input I/O?

Tags: java, sorting, bufferedreader, external-sorting

I am trying to implement simple external sort and I want to read blocks of data at a time. Suppose I read data line by line, and if reading one line means 1 I/O it would defeat the purpose of external sort as there are now too many I/Os. I should be able to read blocks of data at a time. How would I achieve that ?

Comment: Did you read the javadoc? Quote: "...will buffer the input from the specified file. Without buffering, each invocation of read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file"

Comment: so I think it means when you use BufferedReader, 1 I/O of buffering (all of) the file content is executed.. then everytime you call read/readline, it will read from the BufferedReader.. do I understand the javadocs correctly..?

Comment: So what if the file is massive ? And it is not able to buffer the whole file ? What does buffered reader do then ?

Comment: No API will be able to read the whole file in "one I/O" (which I'm assuming means "one system call"). Read online about how buffering works; explaining that is not the point of SO.